# Database Upgrade - Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-migration

I am trying to migrate data during a database upgrade and I don't understand why scenario 1 is working but scenario 2 is throwing an exception:

**Scenario 1**

- Migrate data from Obsolete**Table** into New**Table**

  - Works if ObsoleteTable and NewTable both exists
  - **No error** if ObsoleteTable has been removed already

Query Scenario 1:

```
-- NewTable already created
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where name = 'NewTable')
AND EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where name = 'ObsoleteTable')
BEGIN
    UPDATE newTable
    SET newTable.Name = obsoleteTable.Name
    FROM dbo.NewTable newTable
    INNER JOIN dbo.ObsoleteTable obsoleteTable
        ON obsoleteTable.Id = newTable.Id
END
-- ObsoleteTable will be removed after this step
```

**Scenario 2**

- Migrate from Obsolete**Column** to New**Column**

  - Works if ObsoleteColumn and NewColumn both exists
  - **Gives error!!!** if ObsoleteColumn is removed already

Query Scenario 2:

```
-- NewColumn has been created 
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('MyTable') AND name = 'ObsoleteColumn')
AND EXISTS(select * from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('MyTable') AND name = 'NewColumn')
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET NewColumn = ObsoleteColumn
END
-- Obsolete Column will be removed after this step
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'ObsoleteColumn'.

Both scenarios are basically the same right? Only do the migration to the new structure if the obsolete Table/Column exists. Otherwise ignore.

**If I execute scenario one while ObsoleteTable is already removed. it won't fail. So why does scenario 2 fail?**

Comment: the second says `if something1 AND  something2` where `something1` is false will **never be true** if that table is missing. I do not see the problem with this.

Comment: It's due to the usage of EXISTS vs = that properly cause your confusion.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson In both scenarios I am checking whether the old and the new table/column exists. If either the new or the obsolete does not exist, the data should not (cannot) be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

It is a classic error, the column ObsoleteColumn does not exists. Which means the query will fail even when if the programflow never hits that row

This will also fail:

```
CREATE TABLE #xxx(a int)

IF 1 = 2
SELECT xyz FROM #xxx
```

To avoid it, you can use EXECUTE:

```
IF 1 = 2
  EXEC('UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = ObsoleteColumn')
```

Comment: I understand it is a classic error. But why does my way of working only work for tables but not for columns?

Comment: @hwcverwe that is a really good question. Unfortunately I don't know the answer